# Solving a non homogeneous recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

If we have a recurrence relation like $a_n$ = $a_{n-1} + 5 $ with $a_0=30$, can this be solved using finding characteristic roots and then characteristic roots, I can solve other type of such equations but in cases where $ a_n= a_{n-1} + constant.1^n $ , with a solution for terms like $5.1^n$, the constant term always gets cancelled since same on both sides.

Comment: this sequence is arithmetic : $a_n = 30+5(n-1)$

Comment: Can solve it by iteration method but can it be solved by the way other similar recurrences are solved